# Duplicate nested object in redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Why is there a duplicate nested `todos` object in my redux store?

[image]

components/todoInput.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import actions from '../../actions';

class TodoInput extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      inputText: ''
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      inputText: e.target.value
    });
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.props.dispatch(actions.addTodo(this.state.inputText));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="todo"
          value={this.state.inputText}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Sumbit</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

TodoInput.propTypes = {
  dispatch: PropTypes.func,
};

export default TodoInput;
```

reducers/todo.js

```
import { ADD_TODO } from '../constants/actionTypes';

function getId(state) {
  return state.todos.reduce((maxId, todo) => {
    return Math.max(todo.id, maxId);
  }, -1) + 1;
}

const initialState = {
  todos: [{
    id: 0,
    text: 'Initial Todo',
    completed: false
  }]
};

export default function todos(state = initialState, action) {

  switch (action.type) {

    case ADD_TODO:
      return {
        ...state,
        todos: [{
          text: action.text,
          completed: false,
          id: getId(state)
        }, ...state.todos]
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've provided the nested structure yourself. The todos reducer creates a `todos` key in the state object, and you've provided an initial value of:

```
todos: [{
  id: 0,
  text: 'Initial Todo',
  completed: false
}]
```

So, the state slice created by this reducer is:

```
todos: {
  todos: [{ ... }]
}
```

Just declare the initial state as an array instead of an object with the `todos` key. It sounds like this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Reducers usually live in a branch of the store, decided by the way you create your store.

Using the example from the [redux docs](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/api/combineReducers.md):

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import todos from './todos'
import counter from './counter'

export default combineReducers({
    todos,
    counter
})
```

this will create a store with this structure:

```
{   
    todos: ...,
    counter: ...,
}
```

what goes in these branches is decides by the individual reducer, which should not be aware of the structure of the entire store.

In your case your reducer is creating another key called `todos`, which is why you see the duplication.